# How to move folders between libraries in a site collection without "Open with Explorer"

Tags: document-library

I would like to move multiple folders to an archive library I have set up on SharePoint 2010.

All of the tutorials use the "Open with explorer" way, but I will be working on a mac and do not have that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content and Sturcture is one method to do it through the UI if you have publishing features enabled.  If not, then the only other option I can think of is to use the Document Connection Tool as part of the mac version of Office.

Oh, you could always run a Windows VM in the Mac via Parallels too.